# Why does 403 forbidden error occur when i replace @RequestMapping with @PostMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Given below is the code present in my JSP page  **Sample.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Spring Boot</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h1>Spring Boot  Application</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <form action="sample">
        <label>Name</label> 
        <input type="text" name="name" required></input>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Description</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" required></input>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Price</label> 
        <input type="text" name="price" required></input>
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the code present in my Controller class **SampleController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BooksController {

    @RequestMapping("/sample")
    public String saveBook(@RequestParam("name") String name,@RequestParam("price") int price,
            @RequestParam("description") String description)
    {
            System.out.println(name+" "+price+" "+description);
    }
}
```

when i change

```
<form action="sample">
```

to

```
<form action="sample" method="POST">
```

and when i change

```
@RequestMapping("/sample")
```

to

```
@PostMapping("/sample")
```

Once i do this i am getting 403 forbidden error. i am unable to understand why, because as far as i know @PostMapping has to be used when we submit something to the server, and clearly i am passing a few details such as name, despricption, price which i intent to store in database, but as soon as use @PostMapping i am getting error. where am i going wrong? when should i use @PostMapping and when should i use @RequestMapping?

Comment: Try changing `@Controller` to `@RestController`

Comment: @SSK i dont want to use REST web services , i want a plain Spring MVC Controller

Comment: Maybe CSRF is enabled (do you use Spring Security). If the request doesn't containt a csrf token, you should add it. Disabling CSRF for MVC is *NOT* recommended.

Comment: @MartinTheiss OMG thank you so much , i have been trying to resolve this since weeks, i added the CSRF token , it finally works